# Record the names of columns with a certain value and concatenate in a single string

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have a data frame that contains only 1s and 0s that are a result of some simulations.

```
data = {'Input_A':[1, 0, 0, 1], 
        'Input_B':[1, 0, 1, 0],
        'Input_C':[0, 0, 0, 1], 
        'Output_A':[1, 1, 1, 0],
        'Output_B':[1, 0, 1, 1], 
        'Output_C':[1, 0, 0, 0]} 
  
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

I would like to create a label for each row that is named after its respective active inputs, in order to use it for some visualizations I would like to have.

For example for the first row of the df, the label would be "A + B", for the second one "-", for the third one "B" and so on.

| Input_A | Input_B | Input_C | Output_A | Output_B | Output_C | Label |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 1 | A+B |
| 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | None |
| 0 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 0 | B |
| 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 | A+C |

Comment: please add your expected output as well your own code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you columns have the pattern you show in the example, you can use `df.dot` after filtering the columns that startswith `Input`

```
cols = df.columns[df.columns.str.startswith("Input_")]
df['Label'] = df[cols].dot(cols.str.split("_").str[1]+'+').str[:-1]
```

---

```
print(df)

   Input_A  Input_B  Input_C  Output_A  Output_B  Output_C Label
0        1        1        0         1         1         1   A+B
1        0        0        0         1         0         0      
2        0        1        0         1         1         0     B
3        1        0        1         0         1         0   A+C
```

Comment: This worked flawlessly! Thank you so much! Could you please explain what the dot function does?

Comment: @Rina dot is a matrix multiplication. here we take a dot product between rows with are 1, 0 is ignored since it is False and return the subsequent column names with a `+` appended which acts like a delimiter

Answer (score 0):

My attempt at an easier to understand (although longer) answer:

```
input_cols = [col for col in df.columns if col.startswith('Input')]
input_values = [col.split('_')[1] for col in input_cols]
col_value_map = dict(zip(input_cols, input_values))

def build_label(row):
    inputs = map(col_value_map.get, row.index)
    inputs_one = [name for name, value in zip(inputs, row) if value == 1]
    if inputs_one:
        return '+'.join(inputs_one)
    return None

df[input_cols].apply(build_label, axis=1)
```